# External Ms Access Database Connectivity in my Android Application

Tags: android, database, ms-access

I am developing an application where in I use External Ms Access Database (on PC) as a database for my android application. I have done connectivity for MySql and MSSql using PHP for Android but I want to know as to how shall I proceed for MS Access Database.

Any Tutorials or Snippets are welcome !

Comment: Please give us a better idea of exactly what you hope to accomplish. Do you want your Android app to connect to this database "on PC" over a LAN (WiFi) connection? ...over the Internet? ...as a web service? ...?

Comment: @GordThompson-I want to access database from PC connected over wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) On the Android Side make a function like this:

```
public void connect_access_php(String vars)
{
    List<NameValuePair> itemstring = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    itemstring.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VARIABLE", vars));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit

    try
    {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url_of_php_file");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(itemstring));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String s;
        while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

            //Handle your Values here

        }

     }catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection Problem !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

2) Then on php page, make the connectivity with access file as follows:

```
<?php
$variab = $_REQUEST['VARIABLE'];
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Oops!");
$conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\Desktop\access_file.mdb");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Variable = '".$variab."')";
$data = $conn->Execute($query);

while (!$data->EOF)
{
    echo $data ->Fields[0]->value . ":";
    //echo $data ->Fields[1]->value . " \n";

    $data ->MoveNext();
}
?>
```

With this example you can pass variables to php script and hence to access file for CRUD functions.

Best of Luck !!